# PFQueryTableView not Updating/How to Update

Tags: ios, parse-platform

new day new Problem I guess.

I'm using JASidePanel with 5 Buttons in it,each button Changes the Value of a Variable.
The Variable is used in MyTableController.m as parseClassName.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom the table

        // The className to query on
        if (_sDay==Nil) {
            self.parseClassName = @"Montag";
        }else{
        self.parseClassName = self.sDay;
        }
        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
        self.textKey = @"Fach";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = NO;

        // The number of objects to show per page
        self.objectsPerPage = 5;
    }
    return self;
}




- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hintergrund"]];
    imageView .frame = CGRectMake(0,0,255,458);
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];


    CGRect frameBtn = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 254.0f, 50.0f);
    self.bMonday = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.bMonday setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_rechts_1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.bMonday setTitle:@"Montag" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.bMonday setFrame:frameBtn];
    [self.bMonday addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(monday:)
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:self.bMonday];



    CGRect frameBtn2 = CGRectMake(0.0f, 50.0f, 254.0f, 50.0f);
    self.bTuesday  = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.bTuesday setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_rechts_1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.bTuesday setTitle:@"Dienstag" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.bTuesday setFrame:frameBtn2];
    [self.bTuesday addTarget:self
                      action:@selector(tuesday:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:self.bTuesday];


    CGRect frameBtn3 = CGRectMake(0.0f, 100.0f, 254.0f, 50.0f);
    self.bWendsday = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.bWendsday setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_rechts_1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.bWendsday setTitle:@"Mittwoch" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.bWendsday setFrame:frameBtn3];
    [self.bWendsday addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(wendsday:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:self.bWendsday];


    CGRect frameBtn4 = CGRectMake(0.0f, 150.0f, 254.0f, 50.0f);
    self.bThursday = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.bThursday setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_rechts_1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.bThursday setTitle:@"Donnerstag" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.bThursday setFrame:frameBtn4];
    [self.bThursday addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(thursday:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:self.bThursday];


    CGRect frameBtn5 = CGRectMake(0.0f, 200.0f, 254.0f, 50.0f);
    self.bFriday = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.bFriday setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_rechts_1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.bFriday setTitle:@"Freitag" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.bFriday setFrame:frameBtn5];
    [self.bFriday addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(friday:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:self.bFriday];






}

-(void)monday:(id)sender {

    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController*) self.sidePanelController.centerPanel;

    MyTableController *myNewTableController = (MyTableController*)[navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    myNewTableController.sDay = @"Montag";
    NSLog(@"%@",myNewTableController.sDay);

}

-(void)tuesday:(id)sender {

    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController*) self.sidePanelController.centerPanel;

    MyTableController *myNewTableController = (MyTableController*)[navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    myNewTableController.sDay = @"Dienstag";
    NSLog(@"%@",myNewTableController.sDay);


}
-(void)wendsday:(id)sender {

    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController*) self.sidePanelController.centerPanel;

    MyTableController *myNewTableController = (MyTableController*)[navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    myNewTableController.sDay = @"Mittwoch";
    NSLog(@"%@",myNewTableController.sDay);


}
-(void)thursday:(id)sender {

    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController*) self.sidePanelController.centerPanel;

    MyTableController *myNewTableController = (MyTableController*)[navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    myNewTableController.sDay = @"Donnerstag";
    NSLog(@"%@",myNewTableController.sDay);


}
-(void)friday:(id)sender {

    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController*) self.sidePanelController.centerPanel;

    MyTableController *myNewTableController = (MyTableController*)[navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    myNewTableController.sDay = @"Freitag";
    NSLog(@"%@",myNewTableController.sDay);


}
```

The Problem now is that the PFQueryUITableView isn't displaying the content of the new parseClass, does anybody have an Idea why?
Thanks alot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `monday` ... `friday` methods, you're setting `sDay` but you're not changing the value stored in `parseClassName`. One way you could fix it would be to add the following to each of your methods

`myNewTableController.parseClassName = @"SOME VALUE";`

Another option would be to customize the setter for `sDay` so that it updates `parseClassName` the code would look like the following

```
- (void)setSDay:(NSString *)sDay
{
    if (![_sDay isEqualToString:sDay]) {
        _sDay = sDay;
        self.parseClassName = sDay;
    }
}
```

Comment: You Sir are awesome!
Thanks alot for that superquick solution!
If somebody has the same problem and wants the table to also update after the new class has been asigned he/she can use [myNewTableController loadObjects];